# How to install PWA in magento2.4.2?

Tags: node.js, npm, magento, magento2, progressive-web-apps

I have to **Install PWA studio for Magento 2.4.2**
I did not find a proper way to install PWA studio in Magento
and How to **add magento 2.4.2 to pwa studio**?

Thanks

Comment: have you done it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many articles on how to install PWA for Magento. Have you searched for it on a web browser? You can refer to this installation guide article: https://www.magedelight.com/resources/how-to-install-pwa-studio-in-magento-2-3/.

You can install according to the version of Magento you are using.